# Have table with scrollable content but not header

Tags: android

I want to have a table that has header and content after. However I want the user to be able to scroll the table contents while the header stays visible. The way I did it is by having 2 tables like the following:

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlNames"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:shrinkColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">"
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="dummy"         
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:visibility="invisible" />  
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Player1"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />  
             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Player2"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />  
             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Player3"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />  
             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="player4"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />  
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="dummy"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:visibility="invisible" />"


        </TableRow>
        <View android:layout_height="5dp"/>
    </TableLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlScore"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:shrinkColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />  
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="20"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp" />  
             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="20"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp" />   
             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="20"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp" />  
             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="20"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp" />  
             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="20"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp" />  

        </TableRow>    
</tableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The problem that the header is not aligned with the contents so it ends up like

```
 dummy   Player1  player2  player3  player4  dummy

    20         20       20        20       20     20
```

Is there a way somehow I can make it aligned or maybe have one table with the first row not scrollable but the rest are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to replace your `TableLayout`/`TableRow` structures with `LinearLayout`s. Your header would be a single horizontal `LinearLayout`; your body would be a `ScrollView` around a vertical `LinearLayout` holding horizontal `LinearLayouts` for the rows. Then, you can use things like `android:layout_weight` to assign an amount of space to each "column", which you could keep consistent between your headers and your rows. What you lose is dynamic column sizing.

Another approach would be to roll your own set of container classes that implement your desired pattern, though this is likely to get complicated.

Yet another approach would be to keep your existing scrolling table, but replace the headers with a horizontal `LinearLayout`, and set the sizes of the "columns" of the header in Java code, based upon the proper width of the columns of the body as determined by the `TableLayout`.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.! wow a lot of options yet too complicated:( I don't know how big the header will be unfortunetly because it is modified by human. I wish there was another way